# Accessing a Windows App Object from another Class using C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, class, windows

I have a simple windows application where I have a window with some buttons and labels together with a couple of other classes.

My problem is that I have some methods in the classes in which I would like to update some labels in the main form. How is it possible to access the labels directly from the classes?

thanks

EDIT: A little piece of code will help

Answer (score 2):

The labels on the form are private by default (if added from designer)
One possibility (not recommended) is to change them to public.
A better option would be to add Properties/Methods to set their values.

Comment: noted but i am stuck.

I made the following funcion but still cannot access it:
        public ToolStripStatusLabel StatusLabel (string newStatus)
        {
            tlsStatusLabel.Text = newStatus;
            return tlsStatusLabel;
        }

Comment: @mouthpiec - sounds like you have an instance of 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' but you need to cast to an instance of 'MyForm' - which is where your labels are declared as Properties.

Answer (score 1):

This was frustratingly difficult for me, and the posts here helped. What I wound up doing is:

```
public static ToolStripStatusLabel ts = new ToolStripStatusLabel();      
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ts = toolStripStatusLabel1;
```

...

then, I do this anywhere:

```
ts.Text = "Some Text.";
Application.DoEvents();
```

I found that if I didn't add the DoEvents() statement, the status didn't update frequently enough for me. This will help so much with troubleshooting!

Answer (score 0):

You could just send in a reference to the `Form` that contains the labels, or references to the labels themselves, but that links your code to your GUI and so I would not recommend it. Rather, I'd suggest that in the classes you create events, raise them when an update is needed, then you set up the `Form` to listen for those events and update the GUI as needed.

I'm assuming that the classes are "worker" classes whose methods are called by the `Form` in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not fish directly into the Form's controls collection, using perhaps the Control ID as the identifier?

```
public class LabelChanger
{
  public static void SetLabelText(Form form, string labelID, string labelText)
  {
    Label lbl = form.Controls["labelID"] as Label;
    if(lbl != null)
      lbl.Text = labelText;
  }
}
```

Then, given a form, you can do this -

```
Form f = [[get your form]];
LabelChanger.SetLabelText(f, "lblWhatever", "New Label Text");
```

If those labels are contained within other containers (Panel controls, GroupBox controls etc) then you will have to write a recursive search - however, this would be a good start.